# Where is Captain Picard's window located on the NCC-1701-D exterior?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, uss-enterprise

I've been watching *Star Trek: TNG* episodes and I noticed that several episodes end with Jean-Luc Picard standing at his ready room window, gazing out into space. However, the stars being reflected in the window don't seem to correspond with its location. The bridge is the "bump" on the top of the saucer section, and presumably faces forward towards the bow. This places the Captain's Ready Room on the port side of the "bump" with its window located in that port-side exterior wall. The curvature of the wall next to the window would seem to support that.

However, as shown in the screenshot below, when the ship is at warp the star lines reflected in the window are parallel to it, suggesting the window faces ahead towards the bow:

[image: Picard looks out of the window in the Captain's Ready Room, the star lines are reflected parallel to the window]

Either this is a production/continuity error, or I'm wrong about where the window is facing. **Where exactly is Captain Picard's window located on the NCC-1701-D exterior?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The upper blister is divided into three main sections; The Observation Lounge/meeting room,  the Main Bridge (directly under the dome) and Picard's 'Ready Room' (and replicator nook) as well as a space that we never see on the right but which seems to contains a head and a secondary door to the bridge as well as the shaft for the turbo-lift to the Battle-bridge.

[image: Top down diagram of the upper blister indicating where the Ready Room is in relation to everything else]

<sub><sup>[*Star Trek: The Next Generation USS Enterprise NCC-1701-D Blueprints*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_USS_Enterprise_NCC-1701-D_Blueprints)</sup></sub>

Picard's room seems to be rear-facing, and slightly off to the left.

[image: Outer view of the Enterprise with an arrow pointing to which window belongs to the Ready Room as indicated from the blueprints above]

Comment: Isn't Picard visible during the credits? Or is that a legend?

Comment: @HamSandwich - There are people moving in the observation lounge in the very last few seconds of the credits

Comment: What is "HEAD"?

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish - [Nautical term for bathroom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_(watercraft))

Comment: Man, it’s too bad the Unreal Engine VR Enterprise D got shut down. That would’ve been an amazing thing to experience.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan - Yes. And there certainly aren't any dodgy copies available on the interwebs

Comment: Great answer! I'm guessing either A) no one caught that when adding the stars, or B) someone just decided they looked better coming straight at the window instead of streaking across like they should. Or maybe the Enterprise is flying sideways...