# Do we ever see someone toggle their lights (or close their curtains) in exterior miniature shots?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship

In Star Trek we typically see many exterior space shots of starships, like the Enterprise-D pictured below, where some windows are illuminated and some are dark (see yellow highlights). Up until halfway through Voyager most of these starships shots were done with physical models having physical internal lights, and in my memory the state of the window lights always remained static during those shots. (For obvious budget and TV image quality reasons)

Do we ever see an exterior shot of a physical starship model where the light behind a window switches on or off, or e.g. changes color? Because, hey, at some point somebody must've wanted to go to sleep or was done using the bathroom while 'the camera was on'.

[image: USS Enterprise NCC-1701-D with windows highlighted]

Comment: If you're specifically interested in whether starship lights have been shown to switch on or off in _exterior_ shots (rather than in general), I'd recommend editing the title of the question to more clearly reflect that, since users occasionally post answers based primarily on a question's title, without having properly read the body.

Comment: DS9 used CGI ships from it's 6th season a Voyager from it's 4th so are those the hard limits for the question?https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/CGI

Comment: Good points, both LogicDictates and A.Steer, updated the question to clarify

Comment: "*NEELIX: Computer, lights! Maximum level! Bergamot tea, hot. First thing in the morning I replicate some curtains.*"

Comment: *NEELIX: I know it's illogical, but staring into this murky cloud for hours on end can be a little unsettling. When I was a child, an immense plasma drift passed through the Talaxian system. The stars and the moons were blotted out for months. From horizon to horizon all you could see was this enormous, menacing cloud. Ever since then I've found it a little disturbing to be in nebulas. TUVOK: Perhaps the Captain might give you permission to install curtains.*

Comment: Both in-universe mentions of curtains are from Neelix :-)

Comment: Haha good find @Valorum, as always. I'm curious if this dialogue is accompanied by an exterior shot

Comment: @dennis_vok - Alas no. I can only think of a very few examples of interior-to-exterior shots ever being undertaken. [Picard staring out of his ready-room](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/229302/where-is-captain-picards-window-located-on-the-ncc-1701-d-exterior) for example;

Comment: I vaguely remember reading an interview with someone who worked on the Voyager studio model, where it was described that some of the little windows were made to occasionally darken for a moment as if someone were walking around in front of them. If I can find it again, I'll post an answer (or else, I might simply file it as a false memory).

Comment: In TNG "The Child,", there was a shot where Deanna Troi was putting her "son" to bed. In my memory, she laid her hand on a small wall-mounted console to close a window shutter. I don't know whether or not there was an exterior shot, but I'm pretty sure there was an interior one.

Comment: @SovereignInquiry Good call, I looked up the screenshots on trekcore: there is indeed a window shutter, but it doesn't look like there's a matching exterior shot. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I can think of a few blackout effects when the ships lost power.  Does that count?

Comment: @RobertChapin ah yes, good one! I hadn't thought of that before, it's the most extreme case but it does count indeed. Can you recall any concrete examples?

Answer (score 6):

I thought of the ship-wide blackout effects that happened once in a while.  This was the best answer I could think of because I don't remember individual windows turning on or off.  And interestingly, there didn't seem to be any Memory Alpha articles on the topic.  "Blackout (power)" was limited in scope to planetary power systems.

The first episode that came to mind was “[Contagion](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Contagion_(episode))” (S02E11). A great episode overall.

A shut down effect can be seen in this video, with the Enterprise D window lights turning off progressively in four separate groups.

Moments later there is a power up effect with the lights turning on in four separate groups.  The episode ends with a warbird powering up all at once.  In the remastered version these effects were not applied to the Enterprise saucer section, so only three groups of window lights.  However, the warbird effect was improved to show two or three groups of window lights on that ship as well.

In "[Phantasms](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Phantasms_(episode))" (S07E06) there is a shut down effect where the Enterprise D loses power progressively across five groups of windows.

Several other episodes had blackouts and power fluctuations, but I think they only used interior lighting effects.

I tried to think of any blackouts on Deep Space Nine.  The episode that came to mind was “[Empok Nor](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Empok_Nor_(episode))” (S05E24). It had a power up effect that can be seen in this video.

Comment: Thanks, great find, the videos make it very clear indeed!

Comment: As for how they actually accomplished these effects in the 80s/90s, I'm speculating that they manipulated the 'internal lighting' pass of the miniature film layers in post-production, rather than actually turning the internal lights of the model on and off during filming. Perhaps I'll research this subject as a followup.

Comment: Dennis see the 10:55 mark for how many of us learned about tng effects. (Though not seen here filming the ship was a multiple pass process) 
Reading Rainbow visit to TNG production:  https://youtu.be/PaG6evVcd-w?feature=shared